# Running desktop application c# in mac OSX

Tags: c#, macos, mono, moma

I created a desktop application on windows platform on C#. Now, client wants that application to run on MAC OSX. I installed momA and verified my .exe. I also fixed the warnings and errors that mOMA was giving but now I am confused what to do next. I've never port/compile an application for MAC OSX. Please guide me what do we have to do after verifying from MOMA. I have also compiled my application on mono by the following command in command prompt 'mono dec.exe' and it runs the application perfectly. What else do i need to do now to port it on MAC OSx. Please help